# Angular Custom Validation does not work in SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps, officedev

I have written this code inside of a sharepoint hosted app

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <div ng-app="MyApp">
        <div ng-controller="MyController">
            <p>{{webtitle}}</p>
              <form name="calcform">
                <p>{{calcform.item1.$error}}</p>
                <p>{{calcform.item1.$error}}</p>
                <span ng-show="calcform.item1.$error.numbersonly">item1 must be a number</span>
                <span ng-show="calcform.item2.$error.numbersonly">item2 must be a number</span>
                <input name="item1" ng-model="model.item1" numbersonly />            
                <input name="item2" ng-model="model.item2" numbersonly />
                <input ng-click="add()" type="button" value="+" ng-disabled="calcform.$invalid"/>
                <input ng-click="subtract()" type="button" value="-" ng-disabled="calcform.$invalid" />
                <input ng-click="multiply()" type="button" value="*" ng-disabled="calcform.$invalid"/>
                <input ng-click="divide()" type="button" value="/" ng-disabled="calcform.$invalid"/>                    
              </form>
              <p><font size="14">{{model.result}}</font></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Here you can see that I am using a custom directive to ensure that users are only entering numbers in the input fields.

My directive is implemented as

```
app.directive('numbersonly', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            console.log('came inside directive');

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                var isNan = isNaN(value);
                ctrl.$setValidity('numbersonly', !isNan);
                console.log(ctrl);
                return (!isNan) ? value : undefined;
            });

            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
                var isNan = isNaN(value);
                ctrl.$setValidity('numbersonly', !isNan);
                return value;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

in my debug console log statements I can see that the ctrl object is being set perfectly each time depending on what was entered into the input fields.

But

```
<span ng-show="calcform.item1.$error.numbersonly">item1 must be a number</span>
```

or

```
<p>{{calcform.item1.$error}}</p>
```

show nothing.

Now if I just copy paste this code above into a index.html and app.html and then view the page in a browser... everything works fine and all objects are visible.

But inside of SharePoint 2013, somehow the scope on which the directive sets the values is being lost and the $error object is not visible at all this means that ng-show always evaluates to false.

To make the matters more complex. when I look at the DOM tree in Chrome, I can see that my "form name='calcform'" has been removed by SharePoint

[image]

Comment: I resolved the issue. the problem was that I am using 'form' in the code above rather than ng-form.

Comment: Yes I also found out the same thing after some hours of investigation! thank you